# How to configure the jdk14 logging's pattern

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I guess I can chnage pattern by adding the line java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.pattern, however where to check the pattern information like %u %h etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: The below was written at the time for Java 6. For 7 and later, refer to David's answer below.

AFAIK there is no such property. There is a `java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern` but this is to set the pattern of the *output filename*, not of the logging format.

The way you configure the output format in the util logging API is by setting the [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html). By default, a [`SimpleFormatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) is attached to your `ConsoleHandler`. This formatter simply hardcodes the pattern and doesn't allow you to set it.

If you need a different output format, you'll have to either implement your own `Formatter`, or use a different logging framework, such as [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

Answer (score 30):

This question has already been answered by somebody, but i want to provide some new information:

Since Java 7 it is possible to configure the output pattern for log messages with the `SimpleFormatter`.

You can use this property in your logging properties file:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [%1$tc] %4$s: %2$s - %5$s %6$s%n
```

If you need more information on the pattern syntax have a look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

The digits in the property value above refer to parameters provided to the formatter.
Please refer to the official Java docs for more information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html

Example configuration file `logging.properties`:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
# Pattern works since Java 7
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [%1$tc] %4$s: %2$s - %5$s %6$s%n

# Configure logging levels
# Available log levels are:
# OFF, SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST, ALL

# root logger
.level = WARNING

# child logger
org.example.level = ALL
```

When you call your java program you can specify your configuration file as parameter:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -jar myProgram.jar
```

Comment: I also had to set root level for this to work `.level = ALL`.

Comment: I have tried to go with those directions but cannot get commons-logging.properties to work in my case. Any Clue?

Comment: Sorry, [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging "Apache Commons Logging") is a different framework. This answer is specific to [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html "Java Util Logging (JUL)").

Comment: Set system property (-D...) before -jar statement.
`java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -jar myProgram.jar`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html