# How to use logging.properties for different clases?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have a properties file logger how to do so that I can use it for different classes, but they had a different name?
In my case, for different classes will logger with the same name.

Here is my file **logging.properties**

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = C:\\\temp\\\application_log.txt 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1048576
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 5
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter =
java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
```

Here's the code where I'm trying to load the data:

```
try {
  LogManager.getLogManager (). ReadConfiguration (
  MyClawlerFrame.class.getResourceAsStream ("logging.properties"));
} Catch (IOException ex) {
  System.out.println ("Could not create file. Using the console handler");
  logger.info ("Could not create file. Using the console handler");
  handler = new ConsoleHandler ();
}

logger.info ("Application started.");
```

Comment: Really the filename is `loginning.properties`? Did you mean `logging.properties`?

Comment: @PaulVargas, you could have edited the question rather than comment, as it's obviously a typo.

Comment: This answer is probably relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/15023983/573057