# How to get rid of full package name while logging in java?

Tags: java, logging

We are developing accounting web application which needs specific logs to know what is happening, here
we are using java.util.logging api and some times we need to print some what lengthy messages but in our admin console the message is restricted to some length so we can not able to see entire message in console. We have decided that to remove package name which is prior to log message. Is this good idea?
If it is good please let me know how to do that?

Comment: A better idea would be to remove that strange length restriction from your admin console. Logfiles are files, why not read them with a text editor. Those usually can display very long lines without any issues.

Comment: I can print in the text editor, then i have to go the text file to observe instead of console.

Comment: The idea is more to print to a file so you have the log statements also after your application has crashed or the console buffer is full. If you want to have it still on console, just tail that file if you run on linux. If you have somebody monitoring a console the whole time, then better write a specialized file for that issue or offer a nicer interface (maybe a small program parsing your logfile and searching for interesting patterns).

Answer (score 1):

[Since Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416769/how-to-configure-the-jdk14-loggings-pattern) you can set the property `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` in your logging properties file.

So you could set up shorter messages by trying a different format.

For your specific case the format `[%1$tc] %4$s: %2$s - %5$s %6$s%n` will print the *source* field (package and class name), but the format `[%1$tc] %4$s: %5$s %6$s%n` will not.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416769/how-to-configure-the-jdk14-loggings-pattern) has an example of a logging.properties file. To use the new format use:

`java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [%1$tc] %4$s: %5$s %6$s%n`

Comment: Will, will you please let me know how to add the above format to my logging.properties file

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416769/how-to-configure-the-jdk14-loggings-pattern) has an example of a logging.properties file

Comment: I have added the above line, but it is still printing with full package name.

Comment: Are you calling your program with `java -jar myProgram.jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties`?

Comment: No, I am running my program in the eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a custom formatter which does this for you. Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html

Answer (score -3):

You can implement your own custom Log formatter, extending java.util.logging.Formatter

[Here's an example](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-create-a-custom-logger-formatter/)