# Groovy @Log customize

Tags: logging, groovy, annotations

When I'm using @Log annotation it's output something like:

```
Dec 3, 2013 7:05:13 PM java_util_logging_Logger$info call
INFO: Hello world
```

How can I get actual method and file/linenumber, from where log was called?

Or remove this **java_util_logging_Logger$info call** which is absolutely useless.

Sample script.

```
@Log
class Main {
    public static void main(args) {
        log.info("Hello world")
}   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern that the logger uses is configured in a `logging.properties` file as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15023983/2648)