# Java java.util.logging.logger. Using array objects as arguments

Tags: java, logging

java.util.logging.Logger class provides ability to use such a syntax:

```
int i=0;
log.log(Level.INFO,"int i = {0}", i);
```

This will print out "int i = 0". Unfortunately when I have a bigger value, like 9093, it will print out "int i= 9,023" separating each 3 digits with comma.

The question is how should I get rid of thoose commas? Preferably changing insides of {}. Tried both {0:d} and {0:%d}. Both didnt help. Is it even possible to control parametres like this? Or should I convert my int to string myself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416769/how-to-configure-the-jdk14-loggings-pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the second parameter is a `MessageFormat` which supports "sub-formats". Try

```
log.log(Level.INFO, "int i = {0,number,#}", 1234567);
```

This eliminates grouping characters for me.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html (number sub-formats are interpreted as `DecimalFormat`).

Comment: I want to do the same but it prints
``int i = {0,number,#}" 1234567``
I'm using default java.util.logging.Logger

Do i need to set anything else?