# Single quoted parameters printed verbatim in logged message

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to print some parameters into console with `java.util.logging.Logger.log(Level, String)` method. But the parameter always gets printed verbatim:

```
package loggertest;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoggerTest.class.getName());

      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Some info: {0}.", "foo");
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Some quoted info: '{0}'.", "foo");
   }
}
```

When I run this in Netbeans, the output is:

> ```
> Jan 17, 2017 12:13:43 PM loggertest.LoggerTest main
> INFO: Some info: foo.
> Jan 17, 2017 12:13:43 PM loggertest.LoggerTest main
> INFO: Some quoted info: {0}.
> ```

Clearly, when we use parameters within single quotes (i.e. `'{0}'`), they are printed verbatim. Why does this happen and how do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this problem is that [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) is [being used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749581/1461424).

To quote `MessageFormat`:

> Within a `String`, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string `"'{0}'"` represents string `"{0}"`, not a `FormatElement`. A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes `''` throughout a String.

So, the workaround would be this:

```
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Some correctly quoted info: ''{0}''.", "foo");
```

This would print:

> ```
> Jan 17, 2017 12:37:58 PM loggertest.LoggerTest main
> INFO: Some correctly quoted info: 'foo'.
> ```